# xgboost sklearn wrapper value 0for Parameter num_class should be greater equal to 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to use the `XGBClassifier` wrapper provided by `sklearn` for a multiclass problem. My classes are [0, 1, 2], the objective that I use is `multi:softmax`. When I am trying to fit the classifier I get

> xgboost.core.XGBoostError: value 0for Parameter num_class should be greater equal to 1

If I try to set the num_class parameter the I get the error

> got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_class'

Sklearn is setting this parameter automatically so I am not supposed to pass that argument. But why do I get the first error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to **manually add** the parameter `num_class` to the xgb_param

```
    # Model is an XGBClassifier
    xgb_param = model.get_xgb_params()
    xgb_param['num_class'] = 3
    cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, ...)
```

The **XGBClassifier** does set this value automatically if you use its `fit` method, but does not in the `cv` method

Answer (score 19):

In my case, the same error was thrown during a regular `fit` call. The root of the issue was that the objective was manually set to `multi:softmax`, but there were only 2 classes. Changing it to `binary:logistic` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `xgboost.cv` function? I encountered the same problems but found the solution. Here is my code:

```
    xgb_param = model.get_xgb_params()
    extra = {'num_class': 3}
    xgb_param.update(extra)
    cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, ...)
```

`xgb_param` is the dictionary of the XGBoost model parameters. Then I append a new dict `extra` to it to specify the `num_class`, pass the new dict to the `cv` function. This works.

Answer (score 0):

In xgboost version 1.4.2, what worked for me was including num_class as a parameter to the regressor with a value equal to the number of targets/outputs.

```
params = { "objective": "multi:softmax", 'num_class': 3}
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(**params)
```